# Type hints and @singledispatch: how do I include `Union[...]` in an extensible way?

Tags: python, type-hinting, single-dispatch

I'm refactoring a function that converts a variety of date formats (ie. ISO 8601 string, `datetime.date`, `datetime.datetime`, etc) to a Unix timestamp.

I want the new function to use `@singledispatch` instead of type inspection, but I can't figure out how to retain the previous function's type hinting:

### Old function: using type inspection

```py
import datetime
from typing import Union


MyDateTimeType = Union[int, str, datetime.datetime, datetime.date, None]


# How do I retain this functionality with @singledispatch?
#                    ⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️
def to_unix_ts(date: MyDateTimeType = None) -> Union[int, None]:
    """Convert various date formats to Unix timestamp..."""
    if type(date) is int or date is None:
        return date

    if type(date) is str:
        # Handle string argument...

    elif type(date) is datetime.datetime:
        # Handle datetime argument...

    elif type(date) is datetime.date:
        # Handle date argument...
```

### New function: using `@singledispatch`

```py
import datetime
from functools import singledispatch
from typing import Union


@singledispatch
def to_unix_ts(date) -> Union[int, None]:
    """Handle generic case (probably string type)..."""

@to_unix_ts.register
def _(date: int) -> int:
    return date


@to_unix_ts.register
def _(date: None) -> None:
    return date


@to_unix_ts.register
def _(date: datetime.datetime) -> int:
    return int(date.replace(microsecond=0).timestamp())


# etc...
```

I've explored building the supported types like this:

```
supported_types = [type for type in to_unix_ts.registry.keys()]
MyDateTimeType = Union(supported_types)  # Example, doesn't work
```

...so that it's extensible with future @singledispatch registrations, but I can't get it to work.

**How can I add `Union[...]` style type hints in a `@singledispatch` function in an extensible way?**

Comment: You have to do it by hand, if you actually want your type hints to be worth anything. What use would annotating something with information dynamically generated at runtime give you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My IDE's introspection frequently catches typing errors as I, well, type ;) It intelligently composes types in similar runtime scenarios, such as class inheritance, as you would expect. If I'm not overlooking anything then maybe my issue is less a language one, and more an IDE implementation?

Comment: Maybe this will give you some ideas https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/988#issuecomment-867148941

Answer (score 7):

I think this is what you're looking for. Note that `singledispatch` requires `register(type(None))` instead of `register(None)`. It doesn't support `register(Union[a, b])`, but you can apply multiple `register` decorators to a function...

```py
import datetime
from functools import singledispatch
from typing import Union

MyDateTimeType = Union[
    int,
    None,
    datetime.datetime,
    datetime.date
]

@singledispatch
def to_unix_ts(date: MyDateTimeType) -> Union[int, None]:
    raise NotImplementedError

@to_unix_ts.register(int)
@to_unix_ts.register(type(None))
def _(date: Union[int, None]) -> Union[int, None]:
    return date

@to_unix_ts.register(str)
def _(date: str):
    # Handle string argument...

@to_unix_ts.register(datetime.datetime)
def _(date: datetime.datetime):
    # Handle datetime argument...

@to_unix_ts.register(datetime.date)
def _(date: datetime.date):
    # Handle date argument...
```