# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'register' when using functools.singledispatch

Tags: python, attributeerror, functools, single-dispatch

Goal: create a single-dispatch generic function; as per [functools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch).

I want to use `my_func()` to calculate dtypes: `int` or `list`, in pairs.

Note: I've chosen to implement type hints and to raise errors for my own test cases, outside of the scope of this post.

For many argument data type hints; this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69533664/16852041) uses many `@my_func.register(...)` decorators.

Code:

```
from functools import singledispatch

from typeguard import typechecked
from typing import Union


@singledispatch
@typechecked
def my_func(x, y):
    raise NotImplementedError(f'{type(x)} and or {type(y)} are not supported.')


@my_func.register(int)
def my_func(x: int, y: int) -> Union[int, str]:
    try:
        return round(100 * x / (x + y))
    except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError, AssertionError) as e:
        return f'{e}'


@my_func.register(list)
def my_func(x: list, y: list) -> Union[int, str]:
    try:
        return round(100 * sum(x) / (sum(x) + sum(y)))
    except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError, AssertionError) as e:
        return f'{e}'


a = my_func(1, 2)
print(a)

b = my_func([0, 1], [2, 3])
print(b)
```

```
(venv) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ python3 foo/bar.py 
/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typeguard/__init__.py:1016: UserWarning: no type annotations present -- not typechecking __main__.my_func
  warn('no type annotations present -- not typechecking {}'.format(function_name(func)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/PycharmProjects/project/foo/bar.py", line 22, in <module>
    @my_func.register(list)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'register'
```

Comment: It is expected for builtin package to be shown as not found by pip.

Comment: Also, since you are reusing same name `my_func` for function in position 2 and 3, by the time the command is executed after 2nd `my_func` it overwrites `singledispatch` and `typechecked` function from 1st place and creates a `my_func` instance without these attributes. Hence it does not have `register` attribute. If you would rename 2nd and 3rd `my_func` to `my_func2` and `my_func3` respectively, you would not have the problem.

Comment: I agree functions/ objects shouldn't have the same name; but I assumed that was the part of the point with `@singledispatch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Functions must be uniquely named

Credit to [@Bijay Regmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8591711/bijay-regmi) for pointing this out.

`@typechecked` is placed above only the polymorphed  `@my_func.register` functions; not above the `@singledispatch` function.

Note: you still invoke `my_func()`; I am just testing the polymorphed functions.

```
from functools import singledispatch

from typeguard import typechecked
from typing import Union


@singledispatch
def my_func(x, y):
    raise NotImplementedError(f'{type(x)} and or {type(y)} are not supported.')


@my_func.register(int)
@typechecked
def my_func_int(x: int, y: int) -> Union[int, str]:
    try:
        return round(100 * x / (x + y))
    except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError, AssertionError) as e:
        return f'{e}'


@my_func.register(list)
@typechecked
def my_func_list(x: list, y: list) -> Union[int, str]:
    try:
        return round(100 * sum(x) / (sum(x) + sum(y)))
    except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError, AssertionError) as e:
        return f'{e}'


a = my_func_int(1, 2)
print(a)

b = my_func_list([0, 1], [2, 3])
print(b)
```

```
(venv) me@ubuntu-pcs:~/PycharmProjects/project$ python3 foo/bar.py 
33
17
```